# Process JSON, containing new lines, with JQ and bash

Tags: bash, echo, jq

I receive a JSON with a curl call similar to the following:

```
output="$(curl -s "$api_url")"
```

This output is in the JSON format and has to be processed by jq, it looks like the following:

```
{
    "test": "Hello\nThere!"
}
```

Right now, I'm using the following `echo` pipe combiniation to make jq work:

```
test="$(echo "$output" | jq -r ".test")"
```

However, this won't work for the example input, since it contains new lines in the JSON and JQ errors with `parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 2, column 6`

Is there any way to alter the data so jq can understand it?

Comment: I can't replicate this with Bash 4.4 and jq 1.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Answer (score 8):

So the *literal* input is this:

```
$ output='{
>     "test": "Hello
> There!"
> }'
$ echo "$output" | jq -r ".test"
parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 3, column 7
```

[JSON](https://json.org/) does not have multi-line strings. So if you are getting this literal value from the API it's an *API bug,* and should be fixed server side.

---

Since you say the API actually returns something like `{"test": "Hello\nThere!"}` the problem must be with your commands, because this works with jq 1.5 in Bash 4.4.23:

```
$ output='{"test": "Hello\nThere!"}'
$ echo "$output" | jq -r ".test"
Hello
There!
```

`eval` (which is evil), `echo -e` and other special commands can result in escaped characters being decoded. Try using `printf '%s' "$output"` instead. More information about your environment would be needed to debug this.

Comment: Mh, the API I'm using is Trello's. When using the `curl` command directly, there are no line breaks in the output.

I think the main problem is the `echo` call, since it will interpret those line breaks in the string. But I'm not aware of alternatives

Comment: This example will also fail: `$ output='{"test": "Hello\nThere!"}'`

Comment: @JonasDellinger No, it does not. Did you try it? It prints just fine using jq 1.5 in Bash 4.4.23.

Comment: Unless you are using `echo` with `-e` the escape character will not be changed.

Comment: Huh, so in the end the problem was the shell itself. I was using functions in a file with a `#!/bin/bash` at the top. However, I was sourcing the file and in the end the executing shell was `zsh`, which interpretates escapes by default. Once I added `echo -E`, the function was working correctly. Thanks for your help, definetly put me on the right path! I will write an answer later

Comment: In `bash`, depending on whether `echo '\n'` outputs `\n<newline>` or `<newline><newline>` depends on how bash was built and the environment/options (`posix` and `xpg_echo` here at least). More generally, one can't use `echo` to output arbitrary data.